# How can I populate a table with a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

For my GCSE I need to Create and populate a third table called entries using query scripts. This table should contain foreign keys to allow sensible links to be made with the other two tables, together with the dates of each exam.

Whenever I try to insert records into my entries table it says I am not able to due to the foreign key. [image: My tables and the error which is displayed]

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: What's already in the Entries table?

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Comment: Copy the code and the error message into the question - **in text, not as an image**.

Comment: is subject_id numeric or alphanumeric?

Comment: Please provide the create table scripts of all the three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Basically is a syntax "misplacement":

```
INSERT INTO Entries VALUES (entry_id, subject_id, student_id)
```

Column names should be placed before VALUES clause or, if you supply values for all columns in the table, you can avoid to use it.

```
INSERT INTO Entries (entry_id, subject_id, student_id) VALUES
```

Try it on this way:

```
INSERT INTO Entries VALUES (1,4,1,'date'), (2,8,2,'date'), ...
```